# Dominant term and Big Omega

Tags: algorithms, asymptotics

For the given expression, determine the dominant term and then use the dominant term to classify the algorithm in big-O terms and also in $\Omega$-notation.

$$n^3+n^2\log_2(n)+n^3\log_2(n)$$

So, I believe $n^3$ is the dominant term - but [a plot](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=plot%5Bn%5E3%2C+n%5E3%2Bn%5E2log2%28n%29%2Bn%5E3log2%28n%29%5D) of these shows that $n^3$ doesn't grow as fast as the function? Just starting a course in this and I still haven't got a solid grasp on it yet. I understood Big O should be an upper bound and Big Omega a lower. And how do I use the dominant term to determine the Big Omega?

Comment: What do you think is the dominant term of $1 + \log_2 n$?

Comment: My understanding of dominant terms from previous Calc classes is that it is the term which grows more rapidly, so I would have to guess $log_2(n)$.

Comment: Then what is the dominant term of $n^3 + n^3 \log_2 n$? Hint: Factorize $n^3$.

Comment: Well it would factor to $n^3(1+log_2(n))$. Does that mean the dominant term of the function would be $n^3log_2(n))$? I think that's the part that's got me confused.

Comment: Yes, that's the dominant term.

Comment: Thanks! Think I got it figured out now after a little prodding from you guys. Antonio posted a great explanation of the reasoning behind this below.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maybe thinking about it this way will help.  The dominant term is the one which can be "factored out" and leave behind something bounded.  Here,

$$
n^3 + n^2 \log_2 n + n^3 \log_2 n = n^3 \log_2 n \,\left(\frac{1}{\log_2 n} + \frac{1}{n} + 1\right)
$$

The quantity in parentheses $\frac{1}{\log_2 n} + \frac{1}{n} + 1$ tends to $1$ as $n \to \infty$, so for any constants $C < 1 < D$ you can find an $N \in \mathbb{N}$ such that

$$
C < \frac{1}{\log_2 n} + \frac{1}{n} + 1 < D
$$

for all $n \geq N$.  In particular you find an $N \in \mathbb{N}$ such that

$$
\frac{1}{2} < \frac{1}{\log_2 n} + \frac{1}{n} + 1 < \frac{3}{2}
$$

for all $n \geq N$, say.  (The specific values $1/2$ and $3/2$ aren't too important.)

Thus, for $n \geq N$,

$$
\frac{1}{2} n^3 \log_2 n < n^3 + n^2 \log_2 n + n^3 \log_2 n < \frac{3}{2} n^3 \log_2 n.
$$

This is precisely the statement that

$$
n^3 + n^2 \log_2 n + n^3 \log_2 n = O(n^3 \log_2 n)
$$

and

$$
n^3 + n^2 \log_2 n + n^3 \log_2 n = \Omega(n^3 \log_2 n)
$$

as $n \to \infty$.

Comment: Great answer! That's the way Calvin was pushing me in his comments above, but this is a great explanation of the reasoning. The refresher on dominance helped me a lot.