# How can I tell/compare the asymptotic complexity of a function?

Tags: functions, asymptotics, computer-science

For something, like a quadratic I just take the highest degree and see if it is $\theta(n)$ or $O(n)$ or $\Omega(n)$, correct? So like $2n^2+2n+1$ could be $\theta(n^2)$.

What are the general guidelines/strategies for more complex formulas? For example, something like the $\sum_{i=1}^{n^2}(\frac{3}{4})^i$. Is it gonna be $n^2$ again?

What if I have something like $4lg(n) * 2lg(n)$? Would it be $lg(n)^2$?

And as far as comparing these complexities, should I just graph them until I start remembering which ones grow faster than others?

Links to examples would also help. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 2):

A good reference for how to think about these things is Graham, Knuth, and Patashnik's *Concrete Mathematics*.  I'll  work these examples in detail to give you an idea of how one might proceed.

---

The first example is

$$
f(n) = 2n^2 + 2n + 1.
$$

When $n \geq -1/2$ we have $2n+1 \geq 0$ so that

$$
f(n) \geq 2n^2,
$$

and when $n \geq 1$ we know that $n \leq n^2$ so that

$$
f(n) \leq 2n^2 + 2n^2 + n^2 = 5n^2.
$$

Thus

$$
2n^2 \leq f(n) \leq 5n^2
$$

for $n \geq 1$, which is sufficient to conclude that $f(n) \in \Theta(n^2)$ for $n \geq 1$.

An alternate way to see this is to notice that

$$
\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{f(n)}{2n^2} = 1,
$$

so that for any $\epsilon > 0$ it be true that

$$
1-\epsilon \leq \frac{f(n)}{2n^2} \leq 1+\epsilon
$$

for $n$ large enough.  Thus

$$
2(1-\epsilon)n^2 \leq f(n) \leq 2(1+\epsilon)n^2
$$

for $n$ large enough, which is sufficient to conclude that $f(n) \in \Theta(n^2)$ as $n \to \infty$.

---

The second example is

$$
g(n) = \sum_{i=1}^{n^2} \left(\frac{3}{4}\right)^i.
$$

The first thing to notice is that $\lim_{n \to \infty} g(n)$ actually exists; it is

$$
\lim_{n \to \infty} g(n) = \sum_{i=1}^{\infty} \left(\frac{3}{4}\right)^i = \frac{3/4}{1-3/4} = 3
$$

by the formula for the [geometric series](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometric_series#Formula).  This means that $g(n)$ is of constant order.  Indeed, for any $\epsilon > 0$ it will eventually be true that

$$
3-\epsilon \leq g(n) \leq 3+\epsilon
$$

for $n$ large enough, and this is sufficient to conclude that $g(n) \in \Theta(1)$ as $n \to \infty$.

The appearance of the $n^2$ here (as opposed to just $n$ or even $\log n$) doesn't really factor into the leading-order behavior.  It would, however, show up in the calculation of the *error* $g(n)-3$.

---

The last example, if I understand correctly, is

$$
h(n) = 4\log n \times 2\log n = 8 (\log n)^2.
$$

This is indeed $\Theta\Bigl((\log n)^2\Bigr)$.

---

For intuition on complexities I highly recommend section 9.1 of *Concrete Mathematics*.  You may also be interested in [this question and answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/284815/5531).